# Button not getting positioned

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.nozeens.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/White-Wallpaper-Pattern-Hd-Background-8-HD-Wallpapers.jpg");
}
.button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF6600, #FFCC00);
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #005C66, #008A19);
  }
  25% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #CC66FF, #990099);
  }
  50% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #FF8C9E, #FFF2C7);
  }
  75% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #00A3C7, #00C7B5);
  }
  100% {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #ABFF54, #75FF8A);
  }
}
.button2:hover {
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: american captain;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  animation: color-change 4s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button2">Hover Me For Fun</button>
```

I created this animated button with the animations i just learnt but I can't seem to **position** it i even tried putting *margin-top* but it didn't work. At first I thought that it was because of position so I changed it to *relative* but it is still not working. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: where would you _like_ it to be positioned, compared to how it is?

Comment: towards the center and a little margin above it.

Comment: It seems you are putting the standard styles inside `.button2:hover {...}`. Did you mean for all of these to get applied _only_ on hover? I tried to apply margin inside `.button2 {...}` and that worked for me.

Comment: can you give the code in answer?

Comment: Center horizontally or center vertically or both?

Comment: i wanted both but leave it the problem is solved now. Thnanks! :D